# mysql c++ connector: How to check for and recover from failed connection without crashing

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a mysql program that works most of the time, but I test it with my mysql server shut down and then I start to have problems.

First, I connect to server and try to get database.  Since I am running this when my mysql server is shut off, I get exception when I tell it to connect, and then move on.  Then later on I want to do some other things with the server and before I do I want to check if the connection is open or if it went away for a reason out of my control.

With the connection failed, and then I call the isClosed() function, my program crashes!  I put tests before and after the line of codes and it is clear that once I call isClosed() the program crashes.  This does not make sense for isClosed() to crash because how else am I suppose to know if my connection worked?? (well of course if I am in exception block I can know, but just assume I want to be able to ask if it is closed in other places too).

```
try
    {
        con = drvr->connect(serverLoginParams.hostname, serverLoginParams.username, serverLoginParams.password);
        con->setSchema(db);
    }
catch (sql::SQLException &e) 
    {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "<< __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }

    // ... more code here ... //

if (con->isClosed())
{
     // do something    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have listed, it's possible `con` is never set to something real.

If `drvr->connect(...)` throws an exception, `con` will never be set to a valid pointer, so you can't call `con->isClosed()`, you're not pointing to a valid connection object.

You need to either move the `isClosed()` call into the `try` block, or restructure to bail out after detecting that `connect()` threw an exception.

It's not the code in the `isClosed()` function that is crashing your program, it's the fact you're calling that code on an invalid (potentially `nullptr`, you don't show your declaration/initialization) object, which is undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: This pointer problem makes sense, but I have seen that in my try block that once the first line is called to connect, it goes to the exception, so if I have the ifClosed() in the try block, it won't be called anyway I think.  So if that is the case, then I must restructure the bail out as my only option, correct?  Is there maybe some way for me to give con a valid pointer beside trying to open a connection?

Comment: If connect threw an error, why are you trying to call `isClosed()` anyway? It obviously didn't connect.

Comment: Because there are cases that the connect did work and then later on over hours the mysql server could go down and I want to know if I must attempt a reconnect, so I was using isClosed() for that.  This works fine if the first connection works and give con a valid pointer, but not when the connection fails the first time.

Comment: Then you could do something like `if(con == nullptr || con->isClosed())`, assuming you initialize `con` properly.

Comment: oh great that would work.  I actually initialize con as a null pointer in my class constructor because I don't know any other way to initialize it except to call con = drvr->connect().

Comment: maybe my_init()?  I will try this one.